# Make Predictions with an RNN Using a Multi-dimensional Training Set

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, training-data

I have a 2D matrix `TD` of training data that is a collection of `N` non-linear signals that are functions of time (hence the specification of training **set** in the title of this post). Let `M` denote the number of timesteps for each signal. Each signal shares the same `M`. Therefore, `TD` is an `MxN` matrix. I would like to train my neural network on the entire training set to compute my output weight matrix `Wout.` I would then like to make a prediction on an separate non-linear signal,`yTest`, that is not one of the `N` signals already in `TD` using the trained `Wout`. I would then like to compare the predicted output, `yNN`, with dimensions of `1xM`, to `yTest` with dimensions of `1xM` to see how accurate the prediction is.

My issue is that my current `yTest` and `yNN` both have dimensions of `NxM` instead of `1xM`. My goal is to train the neural network on all `N` training set signals and make a singular `1xM` prediction using a `Wout` that accounts for all `N` nonlinear signals. As a side note, the dimensions of `Wout` are `DxN` where `D` is the number of nodes in my neural network.

I'm not sure if what I am asking is even possible. Is there a way in MATLAB to somehow flatten or reshape `TD` from an `MxN` matrix to a `Mx1` matrix before computing `Wout`? That way `Wout` would be a `Dx1` matrix and the predicted output `yNN` would be a `1xM` matrix like I want it to be?